# "Privileges" link in achievements drop-down links to wrong help center

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, achievements-dialog

I'm a member of two Teams.

While **on the main site**, the link "privileges" in the achievements dialog incorrectly points to a Teams help page (https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000042869#privileges) instead of pointing to the list of privileges on the main site (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

[image]

The link is correct on Meta, and the "badges" link right next to it is correct both on Meta and on main.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for the report, Baum mit Augen! It should be fixed now.